# Dynamically write bash script from another?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to dynamically create and write to a file a bash script from from a current bash script.

```
echo "## Get the IP of the system that was assigned
#!/bin/bash 
ip=$( hostname -i | xargs )
echo $ip " > second_script.sh
```

rather echo out the lines it is executing them, so that I end up with expanded/evaluated variables in second_script.sh.

```
## Get the IP of the system that was assigned
#!/bin/bash
ip=10.0.2.15
...
```

How can I write out bash shell script commands and suppress evaluation, and be able to execute the script later on?

Comment: you may want to put the she-bang line as the first line, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $(hostname)
```

does not work, as you already realized, since the command is expanded. Use single quotes `'` to prevent command expansion:

```
echo '$(hostname)'
```